# Convert "XMLInternalNodeList" to a "DataFrame"

Tags: r

Below is the "XMLInternalNodeList" and I want to convert it to a "DataFrame", so it can be easily read.

```
$item_data
<item_data>
  <item_basic_data>
    <item_unique_id>B003U8EMDA</item_unique_id>
    <item_sku>B003U8EMDA</item_sku>
    <parent_asin>B003U8EMDA</parent_asin>
    <item_upc>885480182565</item_upc>
    <item_mpn>GZDY019-264</item_mpn>
    <item_brand>SIB</item_brand>
  </item_basic_data>
  <merch_cat_list>
    <merch_cat_item>
      <merch_cat_name>1375310031</merch_cat_name>
    </merch_cat_item>
  </merch_cat_list>
</item_data>
```

Result must be like:

```
item_unique_id    item_sku    parent_asin     item_upc    item_mpn    item_brand     merch_cat_name

B003U8EMDA    B003U8EMDA      B003U8EMDA      885480182565     GZDY019-264      SIB            1375310031
```

Comment: Have you tried `xmlToDataFrame()` ?

Comment: Yes, but that doesnot work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested by @Thomas, xmlToDataFrame works. You just have to call it twice.

```
library(XML)
doc <- xmlParse("<item_data>
  <item_basic_data>
    <item_unique_id>B003U8EMDA</item_unique_id>
    <item_sku>B003U8EMDA</item_sku>
    <parent_asin>B003U8EMDA</parent_asin>
    <item_upc>885480182565</item_upc>
    <item_mpn>GZDY019-264</item_mpn>
    <item_brand>SIB</item_brand>
  </item_basic_data>
  <merch_cat_list>
    <merch_cat_item>
      <merch_cat_name>1375310031</merch_cat_name>
    </merch_cat_item>
  </merch_cat_list>
</item_data>")

#call xmlToDataFrame twice for 2 groups of data
ans <- cbind(xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//item_basic_data")),
    xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//merch_cat_item")))
ans
```